# Timer.schedule() leaves an open thread after execution

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

I'm trying to use `Timer.schedule()` to schedule an operation to happen 1s after. The problem I'm having is that after the operation is executed, there's an open thread left hanging and I'm forced to Ctrl+C to close it.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I stop timer from leaving an open thread?

```
public class MyClass {

  public static int WAITING_WINDOW = 1000;

  private boolean waiting = true;

  public MyClass() {}

  public void myMethod() {

    new Timer().schedule(
      new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          setWaiting(false);
        }
      }, WAITING_WINDOW
    );
  }

  public void setWaiting(boolean waiting) {
    this.waiting = waiting;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a reference to the `Timer` and call `Timer.cancel()`.
And read the javadocs, it's all documented there!

Comment: I did read the documentation... "the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection). However, this can take **arbitrarily long** to occur." I was expecting *arbitrarily long* to be in the milliseconds order, not seconds...

This solved my problem though, thanks :D